# Interview question : How to join multiple tables in SQL together at one go

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say you have many tables with the names as Company1, Company2 etc. till Company 1000. Structure as given below:

```
Company 1
product cost($)
A        C1A
B        C1B
C        C1C
```

There are 1000 such tables . All cpmapnies sell 3 products A , B,C . How will you compare your company say Company 520 with all the other 1000 companies.

All these tables are under database `Companies`

How to join all these tables in SQL simultaneously?

I very well know about joins, but I know that at one time we can only join two tables. Is there a way to join multiple tables together in SQL

Expected output

```
product cost($)_Company1  cost($)_Company2   cost($)_Company3   
A        C1A                     C2A          C3A
B        C1B                     C2B          C3B
C        C1C                     C2C          C3C  and so on for all 1000 companies
```

Note in combined expected output, _Company name is appended to cost column names to identify the company corresponding to cost

I was asked this in interview, how you will do it at one go, and I didnt know the answer. Can anyone please help. Structures of tables as in names of columns in all tables is same `product` and `cost($)` being the column names

Comment: Let's start with just comparing three tables.  How would you do that?  Can you include your attempt in the question?

Comment: Yes sure. I will revert soon on the solution for 3 companies

Comment: You should use PIVOT tables, take a look at [Pivot and Unpivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: My answer: Fire the DBA along with anyone else who thought this schema was a good idea, then migrate all data into one table with a column for company number. Then the solution is trivial (as it should be).

Comment: haha bohemian. good one'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this below example. There is no limitation of joining tables.

```
SELECT Company1.Product,
Company1.cost($) 'cost($)_Company1',
Company2.cost($) 'cost($)_Company2',
Company3.cost($) 'cost($)_Company3',
CompanyN.cost($) 'cost($)_CompanyN'
FROM Company1
INNER JOIN Company2 ON Company1.Product = Company2.Product
INNER JOIN Company3 ON Company1.Product = Company3.Product
INNER JOIN CompanyN ON Company1.Product = CompanyN.Product
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following using simple `join`

```
 select
    t1.product,
    t1.cost as 'cost($)_Company1',
    t2.cost as 'cost($)_Company2',
    t3.cost as 'cost($)_Company3',
from company1 t1

join company2 t2
on t1.product = t2.product

join company3 t3
on t2.product = t3.product
order by
    t1.product
```